# Deleting the row in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataGridView bound with the DataTable. I have created a insert and delete trigger for a DataTable, and now I want to execute the particular trigger in the front end for deleting the rows in DataGridView?

How can I do this?

Comment: A bit of code you have written so far will surely help :)

Answer (score 1):

You actually dont need any trigger. Only a bit of a code.
Which rows do you wanna delete, selected ones?
If so you can do:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
        {
            if (cell.ColumnIndex > -1)
            {
                table.Rows.RemoveAt(cell.ColumnIndex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this is for datagridview and not for gridview

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from your question as to what are you trying to do. Some code would have helped.

However if you are sure data in the database is getting updated properly then try calling **[ResetBindings()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resetbindings.aspx)** method on the GridView. It will rebind the data source and show updated values.